# How to reduce boot time in embedded android os.?

Tags: android, optimization, embedded, boot, android-kernel

Initially android os was booting in 28 secs.
Already I have reduced it to 19 secs removing boot-delay,boot animation and disabling preloading of classes. I want to boot os within 10 secs. Please suggest me some tips kernel level or u-boot level to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could move all drivers not needed at startup to modules (.ko files ) and install them with insmod

Comment: @LPs How to remove modules from the android firmware?

Comment: @Charitha That does not seems  reduce boot time significantly.

Comment: @KeshavaKumar Have you reduced the Boot time? If yes how?

Comment: @CharithaRatnayake No.. Unfortunately I did not continue with that project :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(i) Start by measuring the bootup time to profile and analyze the delay causing areas

- use Bootchart for Android
- Kernel prints in Message loggers (Printk)

... check this out http://embien.com/blog/android-boot-time-optimization-tools-analysis/

(ii) Typical delay causing areas are likely to be 
    -

- Bootloader Init
- Kernel init
- Zygote class preloading ** you have addressed this already ?
- Package Scanning
- Starting Services

Check this http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Android_Boot_Time_Optimization#U-boot